# Why unknown variable error trying to save app data?

Tags: android

I'm trying to save a high score in my app by using SharedPreferences. Everything works fine except for line 16 "score". I'm not sure the best way to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textView1;
    EditText editText1;
    Button button1;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("key", score);
        editor.commit();

        String score = (Integer.toString(counter));

        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);}

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == button1){
            counter++;
            editText1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is `score` an `int` variable?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Yes it is. I had a different int variable named counter originally to keep track of clicks on a button.

Comment: My error is Unknown variable or field 'score'

Comment: Can i have score variable value ? it's really Integer ?

Comment: Ok...have you declared the `score` variable properly?

Comment: I originally tried to declare it like so: String score = (Integer.toString(counter));

Comment: It has to be of `int` type. Can you share your code for that (use the 'edit' button towards the bottom-left of your post to add more info)?

Comment: Yes, I've made an edit including the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this example: [Write to Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

> SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
>   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
>   editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
>   editor.commit();

Are you really adding an int? What is the error?

Comment: My error is uknown variable or field 'score'. I am trying to save an integer for a high score. Should I save it as a string instead?

Comment: No as an int, I guess you haven't set/defined score as a value?

Post the whole call so we see where you define score and it will be easier. I guess this is just a typo.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do I still need to include the score string if I am using counter instead?

Comment: Not for the SharedPrefences, you are storing the value as an int as you supposed to. It doesn't seem as if you use score anywhere so I guess it can be removed.

Comment: Please set one answer as accecpted

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialising the `score` var. Try this:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("key", counter);
    editor.commit();
```

BUT, this is wrong since you will only write the value 0 on each activity create call. Put the above code in a method so that you can call it at appropriate times.

Comment: Thank you. When you say that the app will write the value 0 on each activity create call, do you mean when the app restarts the user will have to start at 0 unless I put it in a method that is callable when I need it to be?

Comment: @Bugagull Yes, since `onCreate` will be the first callback in your class, when the above code is called, your variable `counter` will always be 0. Maybe this is your use case but its just a suggestion that keeping the above lines in a method will make your class more modular and cleaner. Also, it will save you from duplicate code when you want to update the value later.

Comment: Thank you. I understand where the problem was and have fixed it.